# In Visual Studio Code, the printWidth setting in Prettier doesn't seem to take effect

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure why, and I also don't understand why curly braces are appearing every time I format the code. How can I fix this? The printWidth setting in the .prettierrc configuration doesn't seem to take effect either.